# VectorPlot "Part 1 of {} does not exist" error

Tags: plotting, bugs, warning-messages, discontinuity

**Bug introduced in 7.0, persisting through 13.2.**

---

I am looking to plot the Magnetic Vector potential, A, as a function of position along the edge of a density plot.  The density plot is fine, and I would combine the two plots using Show.  After searching, I found a similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34003/plotting-velocity-vectors-for-pressure-driven-pipe-flow).  I needed to modify the code a bit to get it to work in version 12.2, however the following code works just fine:

```
ClearAll
μ = 0.02; Px = -0.5; h = 1.0;
vData = Table[{1, j}, {j, -1, 1, 0.1}];
f[y_] := (h^2/(2 μ)) (-Px) (1 - (y/h)^2)
VectorPlot[{f[y], 0}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, -h, h}, VectorPoints -> vData, 
 VectorScaling -> Automatic, VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, 
 Epilog -> {{Red, Thick, Line[{{0, 1}, {4, 1}}]}, {Red, Thick, 
    Line[{{0, -1}, {4, -1}}]}}]
```

And results in this plot:
[image: Vectors along an edge]

However, when I substitute my own code, with as far as I can tell the same approach, I get a "Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist." error.  Besides a different function form, I do not see anything different between my error prone code and the working code above.  Any guidance would be much appreciated!  Thanks.

```
ClearAll
a = 5 10^-3; 
q1 = 1.602 * 10^-10;
eps0 = 8.85418781 * 10^-12; 
qEnclosed[r_] := If[r < a,  (q1 r^3)/a^3, q1];
eField[r_] := qEnclosed[r]/(4 π r^2 eps0);
potSphereTEMP[r_] = -Integrate[eField[r], r ];
potInfinity = Limit[potSphereTEMP[r], {r -> ∞} ];
potSphere[r_] := 
 potSphereTEMP[r] - 
  potInfinity  (* assume potential is zero at infinity *)
vData = Table[{0, j}, {j, -1.5 a, 1.5 a, 0.15 a}]
VectorPlot[{potSphere[y], 0}, {x, -a, a}, {y, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, 
 VectorPoints -> vData, VectorScaling -> Automatic, 
 VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> {{-a, a}, {-1.5 a, 1.5 a}}]
```

Comment: welcome to Mathematica Stackexchange.  In your second code chunk you have eField and eField1. Is this intentional? Otherwise eField1 is undefined.

Comment: Oddly, this seems to work (replacing `efield1` by `efield`): `VectorPlot[{potSphere[y], 0}/1, {x, -a, a}, {y, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, 
 VectorPoints -> vData, VectorScaling -> Automatic, 
 VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> {{-a, a}, {-1.5 a, 1.5 a}}]`

Comment: The problem is found before, but doesn't receive enough attention: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81182/1871 It's broken from the beginning: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R7iU.png

Comment: This bug of `StreamPlot` is essentially the same bug, I believe: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133381/1871

Comment: @Michael E2 that works beautifully, thanks.  Also, it is helpful to know my code not working is due to a long standing bug.

Comment: @xzczd is there a way to contact tech support at Mathematica to make sure they are aware of this?

Comment: Yeah, you can report bug via e-mail: https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback They reply fairly soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be a bug. I'm not sure why it makes a difference -- something to do with `Piecewise` maybe -- but using `?NumericQ` seems to avoid the problem:

```
ClearAll[potSphere]; (***)
a = 5 10^-3;
q1 = 1.602*10^-10;
eps0 = 8.85418781*10^-12;
qEnclosed[r_] := If[r < a, (q1 r^3)/a^3, q1];
eField[r_] := qEnclosed[r]/(4 \[Pi] r^2 eps0);
potSphereTEMP[r_] = -Integrate[eField[r], r];
potInfinity = Limit[potSphereTEMP[r], {r -> \[Infinity]}];
potSphere[r_?NumericQ] :=  (***)
  potSphereTEMP[r] - 
   potInfinity ;(*assume potential is zero at infinity*)
vData = Table[{0, j}, {j, -1.5 a, 1.5 a, 0.15 a}];
VectorPlot[{potSphere[y], 0}/1, {x, -a, a}, {y, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, 
 VectorPoints -> vData, VectorScaling -> Automatic, 
 VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> {{-a, a}, {-1.5 a, 1.5 a}}]
```

[image]

*Addendum: MWE*

Here's simple example of the bug, which seems to center on a vector `List` in which a component contains `Piecewise` for unknown reasons:

```
VectorPlot[{Piecewise[{{y, y > 0}}], 1},
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

> Output is a pink graphic with a "Part is not a Graphics primitive or directive" message. The graphics generated are:
>
> ```
> Graphics[{{}[[1]], {}},...<options>...]
> ```

These work:

1. Head not `List` (see also [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286918/vectorplot-part-1-of-does-not-exist-error#comment714299_286918)):

> ```
>  VectorPlot[Identity@{Piecewise[{{y, y > 0}}], 1},
>   {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
> ```

2. Head `Piecewise`, value a `List` (e.g. `PiecewiseExpand[{Piecewise[{{y, y > 0}}], 1}]`):

> ```
> VectorPlot[Piecewise[{{{0, 1}, y <= 0}}, {y, 1}],
>  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
> ```

These two produce the following graphics:

[image]

Comment: Its a bug, that even the usual Evaluate of the Plot object does not handle. Include the second coordinate into the definition potSphere[r_] := {potSphereTEMP[r] - potInfinity  , 0}. VectorPlot[ potSphere[y] , ...,  Authors of graphic routines expect bite-sized flat-numeric functions. Its the weak point of the LISP philosophy "everything is a list"

Comment: @MichaelE2 didn’t have opportunity to run  (just noting code anomaly) but this answer has been instructive in terms of Mathematica behaviour.